# UIScrollView -setContentOffset : animated YES or NO produce different results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

hei,
I know this sounds stupid. I'm programming my first UIScrollView and I'm trying to set the position of the elements inside the scroll view according to some parameter. I found that I can use setContentOffset for this but no matter what values I feed into that function the result is always the same and I have no idea why? (is it a problem of the contentSize of the scroll view?)

here is my code:

first I set up the scroll view like this:

```
//make view scrollable
scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-216-30)];
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.bounces=NO;
[self.view addSubview: scrollView];
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-110);
```

and later I try to set the position of the scroll view

```
 if(yMultiplier==4){
                [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,imageHeight) animated:NO];
                NSLog(@"4");
            } else
    if(yMultiplier==5){
                [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,imageHeight*2) animated:NO];
                NSLog(@"4");
            }
```

EDIT:
No matter what the y coordinate of the CGPoint is it always scrolls to the exact same point.
I have now tried to use animated: YES. which results in something different. Then it scrolls to the intended position but I have a new problem: As I am adding several images based on what the user types, the scroll works fine for every other image. and for the second image it scrolls back to the original position... 
this is the code for that

```
if(yMultiplier>3){
            CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, imageHeight*3);
            [scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
        }
```

EDIT:
logging the offset in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"offset: %f, %f",scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}`
gives this:

intially:

```
offset: 0.000000, -64.000000
offset: 0.000000, -64.000000
```

when going to right position:

```
2014-06-26 16:56:28.722 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -63.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.739 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -61.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.756 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -57.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.772 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -51.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.789 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -44.000000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.806 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -35.000000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.822 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -25.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.839 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -14.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.855 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, -3.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.872 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 7.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.889 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 18.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.905 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 29.000000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.922 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 39.000000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.939 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 47.000000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.956 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 54.000000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.972 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 59.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:28.989 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 63.500000
2014-06-26 16:56:29.005 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 65.000000
```

with every other images jumping to some wrong place:

```
2014-06-26 16:56:31.516 ualphabets[5058:60b] offset: 0.000000, 12.500000
```

Comment: Please log `contentsize` and `imageheight` ?

Comment: explained the results in an edit above.

Comment: content size: 320.000000, 458.000000
image height 65.099998

Comment: Can you Log the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method to see how the offset is changing ? Set `animated:YES`

Comment: the offset isn't changing. it's staying always at imageHeight or imageHeight*2

Comment: That is because the scrollable height that you have assigned is just `136 pixels`, which is approximately `2*imageHeight`. Try changing the contentSize height to something lot bigger.

Comment: image height isn't changing. how could the offset then do?

Comment: sorry. I just understood what you were talking about. I added the logs from the offset above

Comment: You have tried setting `scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height*20);` and the problem persists ?

Comment: yes I did and yes the problem is still there